# SQL Statement for Listing with count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `registrations` from which I want to know the **total count** by **city** in the following layout.

**Expected Layout**

[image]

Tried preparing the below sql statement which gives me the correct information but not in the correct layout.

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(city LIKE '%location 1%',1, NULL)) 'LOCATION 1',
       COUNT(IF(city LIKE '%location 2%',1, NULL)) 'LOCATION 2',
       COUNT(IF(city LIKE '%location 3%',1, NULL)) 'LOCATION 3'
FROM registrations;
```

The layout from the above query.

**Current Layout**

[image]

How do I re-write the query to return the expected layout?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the query as a `UNION` to get the results in the format you want:

```
SELECT 'LOCATION 1' AS location, COUNT(IF(city LIKE '%location 1%',1, NULL)) AS `count`
FROM registrations
UNION
SELECT 'LOCATION 2', COUNT(IF(city LIKE '%location 2%',1, NULL))
FROM registrations
UNION
SELECT 'LOCATION 3', COUNT(IF(city LIKE '%location 3%',1, NULL))
FROM registrations
```

Comment: How could I automate this for future registrations from different cities?

Comment: @h4kl0rd are the city names exact matches? i.e. do you really need to use `LIKE`, or could you just use `=`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN city LIKE '%location 1%' THEN 'LOCATION 1',
             WHEN city LIKE '%location 2%' THEN 'LOCATION 2',
             WHEN city LIKE '%location 3%' THEN 'LOCATION 3'
        END) as location,
       COUNT(*)
FROM registrations
GROUP BY location;
```